# python-vtk volume rendering call

Tags: python, vtk

I'm having a weird issue volume rendering data with python-vtk.  Everything works fine when I use an isolated script, but when I try and implement the vtk calls in a function it produces some odd results:
[image: render differences]

From what I can tell everything is happening in the exact same order between the two methods, but as you can see they don't come close to matching.  I've uploaded a small dataset & the scripts I am using to produce the two above plots here: [download link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6920345/VTKquestion.tar.gz) (~900kb).  The included `n2vtk.py` is the isolated script (left pic), and `volume.py` is the script that uses the classes & methods from `newvisualizer.py` that produces the weird results (right pic).

I've rendered point particles, spheres, and text with the method shown in `newvisualizer.py` before so I'm not sure why the volume rendering is behaving differently.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!